# JS Regex for full name and phone

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, ecma

**can you help me with regex for :**

1. **full name -**
   can be in english or hebrew  [\u0590-\u05FF]-this is the hebrew letter range.

   need to be 2 or more words,
   that every words contains at least one letter
   (doesnt metter the upper or lower case)

**Exmaples**: Roei Grin, R G, roei grin, r G, roei gr iN,

"רועי גרין","רו ג", רועי גרי ן"

2. **phone number-**
   must be 10 digits.
   must start with 0
   can have (not must) the "-" char, in the three or fourth place.
   **Exmaples**: 0549129393, 058-9210348, 0266-391059

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for both. Names and numbers have good examples, followed by bad examples:

```js
const testNames = [
  'Roei Grin',
  'R G',
  'roei grin',
  'r G',
  'roei gr iN',
  'רועי גרי ן',
  'רו ג',
  'רועי גרין',
  'Bad'
];
const testNumbers = [
  '0549129393',
  '058-9210348',
  '0266-391059',
  '1111',
  '011111111',
  '0999999-999',
  '09999999999'
];
const nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05FF]+( [a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05FF]+)+$/;
const numberRegex = /^0(\d{9}|\d{2}-\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{6})$/;

console.log('testNames:')
testNames.forEach(str => {
  console.log('- "' + str + '"  ==> ' + nameRegex.test(str));
});
console.log('testNumbers:')
testNumbers.forEach(str => {
  console.log('- "' + str + '"  ==> ' + numberRegex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
testNames:
- "Roei Grin"  ==> true
- "R G"  ==> true
- "roei grin"  ==> true
- "r G"  ==> true
- "roei gr iN"  ==> true
- "רועי גרי ן"  ==> true
- "רו ג"  ==> true
- "רועי גרין"  ==> true
- "Bad"  ==> false
testNumbers:
- "0549129393"  ==> true
- "058-9210348"  ==> true
- "0266-391059"  ==> true
- "1111"  ==> false
- "011111111"  ==> false
- "0999999-999"  ==> false
- "09999999999"  ==> false
```

Explanation of `nameRegex`:

- `^` ... `$` - anchor at start and end of string
- `[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05FF]+` - start with 1+ characters of alphabet and/or hebrew
- `( [a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05FF]+)+` - followed by 1+ pattern of: single space, followed by 1+ characters of alphabet and/or hebrew

Explanation of `numberRegex`:

- `^` ... `$` - anchor at start and end of string
- `0` - start with `0`
- `(\d{9}|\d{2}-\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{6})` - followed by either:

  - 9 digits
  - or 2 digits, `-`, 7 digits
  - or 3 digits, `-`, 6 digits

Comment: @Roei Grinshpan: Does this fit your needs? Any question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use, this reg exp for your mask phone - `^[0]{1}(([\d]{2}[-]{0}[\d]{7})|([\d]{3}[-]{1}[\d]{6})|([\d]{2}[-]{1}[\d]{7}))`